# Create nodes and relationships in Neo4j with inputs as a pandas DataFrame with py2neo

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, neo4j, py2neo

I have the output as a pandas data frame. I am trying to write a cypher query to give this data frame as the input to Neo4j and create a graph with relations extracted from its source and target.

If anyone has any idea on how to proceed further, please guide me in this.

[Pandas Dataframe]

[image: 1]

Comment: paste the dataframe as text/code .remove screenshot and also show us your desired output

Comment: i found a basic implementation about what are u trying to achieve 
```python3
query_string = '''
MATCH (c:Category) 
RETURN c.category_name, SIZE(()-[:IN_CATEGORY]->(c)) AS inDegree 
ORDER BY inDegree DESC LIMIT 20
'''
top_cat_df = pd.DataFrame([dict(_) for _ in conn.query(query_string)])
top_cat_df.head(20)
```
also see: [Neo4j from Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/neo4j-cypher-python-7a919a372be7)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is how you pass the panda dataframe into the query. I used string format to parameterized source, target and relationship type.

```
from py2neo import Graph

df = pd.DataFrame([['Kimbal','sibling', 'Elon'],
                   ['Boring', 'owned_by', 'Elon']], 
                  columns=['source', 'relation_type', 'target'])

query = """
    MERGE (s:Source {{name: '{source}'}})
    MERGE (t:Target {{name: '{target}'}})
    MERGE (s)-[r:{relation_type}]->(t)
    RETURN s.name,t.name,type(r) as relation_type;"""

graph = Graph("bolt://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j", "awesome_password"))
for d in df.values:
    result = graph.run(query.format(source=d[0], relation_type=d[1], target=d[2]))
    d = result.data()
    print(d)
```

Result:

```
[{'s.name': 'Kimbal', 't.name': 'Elon', 'relation_type': 'sibling'}]
[{'s.name': 'Boring', 't.name': 'Elon', 'relation_type': 'owned_by'}]
```